# How to navigate from one page to another in Ionic?

Tags: angular7, ionic4

Need some help implementing a redirect to a certain page in Ionic. I have tried the following code samples, but none of them work for me:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.flightdetailsPage);

//this.router.navigateByUrl('/flightdetails');
//this.navCtrl.push('flightdetails');
// this.navCtrl.navigateForward("flightdetails");
//this.router.navigate(['flightdetails']);


this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.flightdetailsPage);

//this.router.navigateByUrl('/flightdetails');
//this.navCtrl.push('flightdetails');
// this.navCtrl.navigateForward("flightdetails");
//this.router.navigate(['flightdetails']);


this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.flightdetailsPage);

//this.router.navigateByUrl('/flightdetails');
//this.navCtrl.push('flightdetails');
// this.navCtrl.navigateForward("flightdetails");
//this.router.navigate(['flightdetails']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below format:

**Way 1:**

this._router.navigate(["/welcome"], { queryParams: { data: "name" } });

to access the queryParams use:
this.router.snapshot.queryParams["data"];

syntax:

this.router.navigate([_path] , _data)

**Way 2:**

```
this._router.navigate(["/welcome", { data: "name" }]);
```

to access the data :

```
this.router.snapshot.params["data"]
```

Comment: Not working any one getting ERROR Error: "[object Object]" error

Comment: i use following but getting errorgotoUserProfile(userid) {
    //console.log(" you click ",userid);
   // this.router.navigate(['/user-profile-details',{data:"vinod"}]);
    this.router.navigate(["/user-profile-details"], { queryParams: { data: userid } });
    // this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/user-profile-details'],{});
  }